# Is there any way to associate a file descriptor with user defined data?

Tags: c, sockets, posix

I am writing a client-server application, and it uses POSIX `poll` function to provide a form of concurrent client handling. Clients also have state and other related data, which is stored in a client structure.

My immediate problem is that when I get a hint from `poll` to do I/O on a socket file descriptor that is associated with a client (conceptually), I have to actually match the file descriptor to its associated client data structure. Currently I do a `O(n_clients)` lookup (my client data structure stores the descriptor), but I was wondering whether there exists a better alternative?

Comment: Have you profiled your program and did you find that this is the bottleneck?

Comment: No, I haven't :( But memory is cheaper than CPU don't you think? I am tired of my laptop getting hot...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  If there were, it would have to be tracked by the kernel, and looking up that data would therefore involve a system call.  The cost of a system call is an order of magnitude more expensive than doing an O(n) lookup in user space.

How many clients are you dealing with at once?  Unless it's on the order of hundreds or more, the cost of a lookup is going to be miniscule compared to the cost of doing any sort of I/O.

Instead of using an O(n) lookup, you could also just use an array indexed by the file descriptor, assuming you won't have more than a certain number of descriptors open at once.  For example:

```
#define MY_MAX_FD 1024  // Tune this to your needs
void *per_fd_data[MY_MAX_FD];

void *get_per_fd_data(int fd)
{
    assert(fd >= 0);
    if(fd < MY_MAX_FD)
        return per_fd_data[fd];
    else
    {
        // Look up fd in a dynamic associative array (left as an exercise to the
        // reader)
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out that file descriptors are reasonable to use as array indices

Comment: @R Wouldn't that make a very big array? I mean, POSIX file descriptors are `int`s, right?

Comment: By the way @Adam, there is already a system call involved - `poll`, so it is not entirely correct when you imply that an additional call would be needed to lookup the user data. For instance if `pollfd` had space for a `void*` which would be the user defined data, and the `poll` call would simply "passthru" that data upon returning, then we would be all set.

Answer (score 2):

Cheapest is to just make a fixed-size array of connection structures, with {state, *context, ..., maybe callback functions} per entry, **indexed by fd** (=O(1)). Memory is cheap, and you can afford a few hundred or thousand file descriptors and table entries.

EDIT: You dont *need* to make it fixed size. If your pollstructure or fdset is fixed: make it fixed; otherwise use getdtablesize() or getrlimit() to get the number of entries to allocate.

Comment: One problem with an array is that in order to iterate over the valid fd's you have to iterate over all the invalid slots as well ... not good considering that with select() or poll() you typically have to iterate over the FD's at least twice per event loop iteration (once to do the FD_SET() calls before the select(), and again afterwards for the FD_ISSET() calls).  Better to use a map (or similar) instead.

Comment: Not iterating, but indexing. "array[fd].stuff". Remeber an fd is a small int with values [0, fd_max). You only have to catch the case of fd= -1, which can be a result of open(), listen() or accept(). The only iteration you suffer is from the pollfd[] or fd_set arrays.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [`poll()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/poll.html) or [`select()`/`pselect()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/select.html) then you should keep the data yourself, e.g. in a hash table or array as others have mentioned.  That is the most portable solution.  Some of the alternative interfaces do have ways to associate your own user data.  For example using [asynchronous I/O](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_08_02) (e.g. [`aio_read()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/aio_read.html)), you can supply a user value [`sigev_value`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04_02) that can be passed to a signal handler or thread upon completion of the asynchronous request.  The Linux [epoll](http://kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/epoll_wait.2.html) interface also allows user data to be specified for each file descriptor in the set.

Comment: Hash table is only a reasonable solution if your hash function is the identify function and your buckets are all size-1... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Adding to all the other, very useful answers, I wanted to make the following information available, hoping it would be useful for others, in the spirit of knowledge base.

The thing is that if we assume a POSIX-compliant system, http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_14, it specifies the following (emphasis mine):

> All functions that open one or more file descriptors shall, unless specified otherwise, atomically allocate the *lowest numbered available (that is, not already open in the calling process) file descriptor* at the time of each allocation. Where a single function allocates two file descriptors (for example, `pipe()` or `socketpair()`), the allocations may be independent and therefore applications should not expect them to have adjacent values or depend on which has the higher value.

This allows a program to simply reserve an array up to a number of descriptors it wants to support, where an open descriptor can just be used as array subscript to reference something like client connection related data. Basically, an open file descriptor on such systems can be straightforwardly used as an index into a table which is implemented as an array. After all, file descriptor numbers will not only grow upwards from lowest availbale values, they also seem to be reused -- if you close descriptor 10, while you still have descriptors 11 and upwards open, next time you open a descriptor, a POSIX-compliant system will open description with index 10. This also makes reuse of rows in your fd-indexed table very simple.